# Drop a column based on row values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How could I drop a column where the row value is equal to 1?

Example:
I want to keep the staff names where No. leaves taken is 0 and drop the rest of the columns

```
                     Jack    Mary    Huin   Lean
No. sales            340     200     100     122
No. leaves taken       1       0       3       0
```

Comment: df[df["Jack"]!=1] ?

Comment: Is No. leaves taken on the index?

Comment: `df.loc[:,(df.loc["No. leaves taken"] == 0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .loc

```
df = df.loc[:, (df.filter(items=["No.leaves taken"], axis=0).eq(0)).any()]
print(df)

                 Mary  Lean
                           
No. sales         200   122
No.leaves taken     0     0
```

Comment: Will this not remove columns if Sales=0 as well?